# Почему в flask не отображает стили

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Я создаю сайт на flask. Я хочу создать стиль страницы в отдельном файле. Но стиль не используется, текст остается прежним. Вот мой код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>sheduler</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="h1">Заголовок</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот код стиля:

```
.h1{
color:blue;
}
```

Вот код python:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")
app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Вот пути:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался html и css писать в одном файле это помогло, но мне нужно, чтоб каждый файл html и css были отдельно.

Comment: Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо файл `style.css` взять из папки `templates` и поместить в папку `static` так как файл стилей это не файл шаблона, а статический файл. Далее подключить его в шапке таким способом:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```